# Click to Chat URL for WhatsApp not opening the WhatsApp app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, messages, sms, url, whatsapp.app

When SMS with shortened Click to Chat URL for WhatsApp is received on the iPhone, clicking it leads me to the App Store instead of opening chat in WhatsApp, despite WhatsApp being installed on the device.

In another post it was recommended to use Whatsapp:// but I don't believe that resolves my issue, since services like BITLY won't accept that URL to shorten it.
Have tested using Whatsapp:// within BITLY but it is not accepted as valid URL.

The question is... how can I shorten the normal Click to Chat URL from Whatsapp (with pre-filled in message). This was working fine for years, and is still working for Android.

At the moment, the bitly link redirect to Safari to be resolved and then should pass the focus back to Whatsapp APP. Now it redirects to the Whatsapp APP in the App Store.

I suspect a recent iOS Security update could be causing this change in bevahiour.

Here is the link to the Whatsapp FAQ on how to use Click to Chat: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/

Just to confirm... the link works fine if unshortened.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: As for your question, could you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/364326/edit) it to clarify if this is only a problem when the message is received on the iPhone? That is, have you tested your messages on other devices with WhatsApp installed to see what happens? Also, it'd be good to include the version of iOS you're running in case this turns out to be relevant. Finally, it's not clear if you've actually tried to use `Whatsapp://` or not? If not, please try it and share the results.

Comment: Thanks for the update on the question. Appreciated

Comment: Why don't you use `wa.me`? Also if you replace android with iPhone in the FAQ link, the same page appears, but better link that one though.